# HttpContext.User or Page.User in a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I'm coding in a View in Asp.net MVC and I want to get the current user, is it better to use

`Page.User`

or

`HttpContext.User`

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Page.User` returns `this.Context.User` which is exactly the same as `HttpContext.User`, so it makes no difference, both point to the same object in memory. As a side note, I would recommend you not to use either of these in a View Page, let the controller pass the needed data to the view in which case you have a third choise which is the [Controller.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property.

Comment: Why is it not recommended to use Page.User or HttpContext.User and to pass the user info through the controller?

Comment: Because in an MVC model the role of a View is to show data that is being passed by the controller. It is not a view's responsibility to pull data.